# Android Studio - use modules to generate multiple branded apks

Tags: java, android, module

Sorry, I don't really know how to arrange title in my case, but I'll try to explain it now. Let's assume I have some app that uses some rest calls via Retrofit and consumes some data via get/post api calls.

Now I need to create multiple similar apps, each app will need to have different look (splash, icons etc), different name and different urls to acces backend api (rest webservices), but all the rest, including layouts and logic will be the same

My idea is to use multiple modules and make all of them to use the same, shared core. Each module will contain its own drawables and some configs (like urls to api) and its own signing key. Each module should generate separate apk, using its own key.

Is this possible to get in Android Studio? How to share logic between modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Product Flavors", it allows you to build multiple apps with same core code,

here an example gradle config :

```
android {

  signingConfigs {
      flavor1 {
          storeFile file("keystore")
          storePassword "secret"
          keyAlias "aliasForFlavor1"
          keyPassword "secretFlavor1"
      }

      flavor2 {
          storeFile file("keystore")
          storePassword "secret"
          keyAlias "aliasForFlavor2"
          keyPassword "secretFlavor2"
      }
  }

defaultConfig {...}
buildTypes {...}
productFlavors {
  def demoSigning = signingConfigs.flavor1
  def fullSigning = signingConfigs.flavor2
    demo {
        signingConfig demoSigning
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "-demo"
    }
    full {
        signingConfig fullSigning
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
  }
}
```

it will create multiple folders for source files for every flavors you created before. So, you can separate your code to have different URL, requests and drawables etc...

you can have more detail here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html